# Asp.net MVC Web Application Hanging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, visual-studio-2013

We recently switched our MVC Web Application to use asynchronous tasks.  A few days ago, the application began hanging.  The problem is that we are not sure if it is the async stuff causing the issue, the Debugger in Visual Studio 2013, or IIS.  The application starts up fine, but as you begin to click on different pages it gets slower and slower moving from method to method.  When you stop debugging and try to restart.  You get the message that "another debugger is running".  It takes a VERY long time for it to reset so you can begin debugging again.  Sometimes I have to close Visual Studio and reopen for it to release.  My question is, could the async Tasks be causing this behavior?  Is there anyway to see how long each task takes to execute or if the threads are being released?  I don't really know where to start to figure out the problem.  Any suggestions, direction or article suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just curious, what browser are you using to view your web application?

Comment: You could see how many threads are currently open in visual studio if you can reproduce locally. Just pause the debugger at some point and open the Threads window. You can dubble click on a thread to go to it and see if there is anything that stands out (ie. stopped on the same spot). Within each thread you also have access to the call stack for if you need to see that.

Comment: I use both IE 11 and Chrome when testing.

Comment: I did try looking at the threads but I couldn't really tell what was going on, although I did notice a whole lot of threads.  Is there anyway to tell if they are being released?  I'm not sure what to look for.

Comment: You might find this useful: [.NET Hang Debugging Walkthrough](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2006/10/16/net-hang-debugging-walkthrough/)